# Android exclude from recents not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an activity that I want not be seen in the Recents items. I have used the following in my Manifest file :

```
<activity
        android:name=".WidgetLayout"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme.Dialog">
```

It works perfectly well on all android versions but when I try it on Lollipop (SDK 21) it shows up always in the Recent items. So is it an OS bug as stated by many or I have made some error. Is there a solution to the problem if yes then how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue into Android 5.0, since L preview.

Try with **android:taskAffinity**

```
      android:taskAffinity=".WidgetLayout"
      android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

You Should try adding  `android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"`